# Is it possible to implement the following design pattern using TestNG?

Tags: java, design-patterns, testng

I'm working in a test suite and I'm currently trying to implement the following design based on the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
    <parameter name="server" value="http://www.smartdate.com/"/>
      <test name="Test" preserve-order="false">
        <classes>
            <class name="testscripts.SetUp"/>
            <class name="testscripts.TestHome"/>
        </classes> 
  </test>
</suite>
```

In this short example I want the following:

1. Run SetUp configurations (this class only defines `@BeforeSuite`, `@AfterSuite` and may be other annotations like `@BeforeClass`, `@AfterClass`, no `@Test` methods here).
2. Run all the following classes, in this example just one, "TestHome" but maintaining the previous configurations.

Now the question is, is this possible?

Thank you in advance,
Nahuel

Answer (score 0):

Well, have you tried your proposed design at all? It should work. Try it and report back if something is not working as expected.

Comment: Yes I tried, but SetUp is executed and all TestHome tests fail, it seems that the session/instance created at SetUp is ended, any workaround to implement something like this?

Comment: Without knowing what your SetUp class actually does and how persistent what it does needs to be, it's hard to answer.